# Would multiple t-tests be appropriate

Tags: anova, t-test, repeated-measures, isotonic

I have reaction time data from four different age groups, and I am hoping to prove that reaction time improves with age. I know that ANOVA would be preferred to determine if age has an effect, but I am not looking to simply prove that or to compare each group to every other group. Instead, I only want to compare `Group 1` to `Group 2`, `Group 2` to `Group 3`, and `Group 3` to `Group 4` (with the hope that `Group 4` mean is less than `Group 3` mean, `Group 3` is less than `Group 2`, and `Group 2` is less than `Group 1`).

Would three t-tests be appropriate here, or would a different method be preferable?

Comment: Do you really want to carve up a continuous variable (age) into arbitrary groups? Treating age as a continuous predictor in a regression analysis seems the best solution for what you're trying to do, i.e. show a monotonically increasing trend with age.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do a series of one sided tests for such a directional alternative, though it's also possible to test such hypotheses in a single test.

There are several nonparametric tests - e.g. the [Jonckheere-Terpstra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jonckheere%27s_trend_test) and Match test for ordered alternatives (found, for example, in Neave and Worthington's, 1988 book *Distribution-Free Tests.*).

There are also parametric approaches for testing for trend. The book by Barlow, Bartholemew, Bremner and Brunk (1972) (*Statistical Inference Under Order Restrictions*) discusses some, though there are numerous more recent papers, some based on [isotonic regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotonic_regression) approaches, and some on linear-score tests for example.

There's also Bayesian approaches. For example Gelfand et al (1990) and  Gelfand et al (1992) discuss using MCMC for an ordered alternatives problem (the second in a two-way situation).

Gelfand, Hills, Racine-Poon, and Smith, (1990),
*Illustration of Bayesian Inference in Normal Data Models Using Gibbs Sampling*,
Journal of the American Statistical Association, **85**:412 (Dec.), pp. 972-985

Gelfand, A.E., Smith, A.F. & Lee, T. (1992),
*Bayesian analysis of constrained parameter and truncated data problems using Gibbs sampling,*
Journal of the American Statistical Association, **87**, pp. 523–532

Of those, I'd be inclined to just do a Jonckheere-Terpstra, simply because its probably the most readily doable without going to extra effort; it can be found in quite a few packages, though some of the parametric trend tests may be available to you as well.